# Alternate of Class Object while creating formatted List

Tags: c#, .net, list, datatable

I have a Datatable which is being added to `List` with specific format. Now as per my requirement I do not want to create generic list from a Class while preserving the format of my data but not able to do it. Below is my code

```
  List<Data> datalist = new List<Data>();
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
     Data dd1 = new Data();

     dd1.ID = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]);
     dd1.STATUS = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Name"]);
     dd1.TYPE = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TYPE"]);
     datalist.Add(dd1);
   }
```

Is there a way to remove dependency of class `Data` from the above code keeping the format same?

Comment: you can use `anonymous type` with `linq` on your `dt`

Comment: @ershoaib Could you please share an example..Thanks

Comment: answer posted, view the answer might be it help you :)

Comment: How do you use datalist  later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `linq` query on your `dt` like below and project your result into `anonymous type` like.

```
var datalist = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select new
                {
                    ID = r.Field<string>("ID"),
                    Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
                    TYPE = r.Field<string>("TYPE"),
                }).ToList();
```

If you want to get `name` for some `Id` from `datalist` then.

```
string name = datalist.Where(x => x.ID == "123").FirstOrDefault()?.Name;
```

Comment: Thanks..I will implement the solution and keep you posted

Comment: @RAM, i added one more linq query for your knowledge purpose. view the updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary in its place. No more `Data` class dependency, but the same basic data and format!

```
var datalist = new List<IDictionary<string, string>>();
for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    var data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "ID", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]) },
        { "STATUS", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Name"]) },
        { "TYPE", Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["TYPE"]) }
    };
    datalist.Add(data);
}
```

Then you'd just access the values `datalist[i]["ID"]` instead of `datalist[i].ID`.

Comment: Thanks..I will implement the solution and keep you posted.